# What is the best way to create background service to listen firebase database always?

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, android-service

I have heard about the types of services likes JobScheduler, WorkerManager, IntentService, AlarmManager. But Im confused to choose best approach to achieve my requirement with various use cases like on reboot, kill the app, force stop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the service to stay running for long periods of time in the background, then a good start would be a sticky service .. basically you will create a class that extends the `service` class and you can use `START_STICKY` result to keep it running for long periods of time.

```
public class MyService extends Service {
   @Nullable
   @Override
   public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
      return null;
   }

   @Override
   public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
      Toast.makeText(this, "Service Started", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
      //this commandresult makes the service a sticky service
      return START_STICKY;
   }

   //you can create a class that runs on a timer or a loop 
   // inside this service and it will continue running until the OS or user kills it
   // create a timer then query your database inside this class and send out
   //notifications accordingly

   @Override
   public void onDestroy() {
      super.onDestroy();
      Toast.makeText(this, "Service Destroyed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
   }
}
```

Source: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_services.htm